# Architectural pattern for testable C code

Tags: c#, architecture, testing, c, architectural-patterns

I wrote a lot of software in C# and Python. I tried to make the overall architecture testable by using the "Clean Architecture" and Dependency Injection. This works well for C# (and python).

Now I move to a new company where I will program C (it will be a new codebase). Some years ago I already wrote much C, but without a strong focus on testing. This time I like to create a clean and testable architecture which allows to test anything.

Does a best pratice like the "Clean Architecture", "Onion Architecture" or some other architectural pattern exist that leads to well testable C code? (of course, given the code is well written)

Comment: If you don't already have one, get a copy of "Writing Solid Code" by Steve Maguire. It is less about testing, but about writing robust code (with a strong focus on C). That will be more helpful than anything else in your daily work.

Comment: The type of architecture you choose has more to do with the kind of application you are writing than the choice of language.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The nice thing about architectural patterns is that they are largely language independent. Some languages may have better or worse support for the basic constructs that a particular pattern is built upon.

Many architectural patterns are built upon Object Oriented concepts. C does not have built-in OO features, but you can actually implement OO designs in C.

The standard techniques for testing code in C are

- Swap out production code for stubs/mocks/fakes at the file level by linking a different file into the test executable
- Use preprocessor macros to disable functionality not wanted during testing
- Write OO-style code and use DI